# xsl - string translate in my code - Help required

Tags: string, xslt, translate, replaceall

I have an xsl code where I need to implement replaceAll functionality as we do in Java. I tried
trasnlate function but it was not working. I am not sure where and how to use the function in the below code and you please help on this.

```
<xsl:template match="warning">
    <xsl:param name="drugsSub" select="'false'"/>
    <tr>
      <td class="dataRowBorderBottom rowColor" style="width: 35%; padding-right: 5px; font-size:.85em;">
        **<xsl:apply-templates select="translate(warningId,'/','/ ')">**    This is not working. I want translate function to work both warningId. A value comes for this variable from some other file.
          <xsl:with-param name="drugsSub" select="$drugsSub"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </td>
      <td class="dataRowBorderBottom rowColor leftPadding" style="width: auto; padding-bottom: 15px; font-size:.85em;">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="severity"/>
      </td>
      <td class="dataRowBorderBottom rowColor leftPadding" style="width: 13%;font-size:.85em;">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="documentationRating"/>
      </td>
      <td class="dataRowBorderBottom rowColor leftPadding" style="width: 35%; padding-top: 3px; font-size:.85em;">
        <xsl:value-of select="warningText"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please specify what you want to happen. Sample input and output would be fine. It's likely that `translate()` doesn't do what you think it does. Maybe you're trying to replace each `/` character with the string `/ `? If so, the best answer depends on whether you can use XSLT 2.0, or are stuck with 1.0.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280079/xsl-multiple-search-and-replace-function

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you why the code doesn't work: translate() produces a string, and you can't apply-templates to a string (only to a node-set).

But I can't tell you how to fix it, because I have no idea what you are trying to achieve.