# XSLT - Extract and manipulate portion of XML data

Tags: xslt

The input XML:

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Description><![CDATA[Audience: Andrew Reed, Senior Training Specialist, Microsoft Corporation<br/>This session is for individuals who spend significant time writing and creating documents and have some familiarity with Microsoft Word.<br/>Thanks.]]></Description>
</root>
```

The XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template  match="/root">
    <div>
      <xsl:value-of  disable-output-escaping="yes" select="Description"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to add a couple of more BR tags after first occurrence of BR, that's after Audience line and before other description starts.
Can you please modify my XSLT to get the desired output?

So I want output like below:

```
Audience: Andrew Reed, Senior Training Specialist, Microsoft Corporation


This session is for individuals who spend significant time writing and creating documents and have some familiarity with Microsoft Word.


Thanks.
```

Comment: "I need to add a couple of more BR tags" - but the sample output you showed doesn't have any BR tags in it. Do you mean you want to transform each `<br/>` element to three carriage returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be nice if your input data had the `<br/>` elements as actual elements, instead of being escaped, so that they could be selected directly using XPath.

But since they are as they are, you can use regexp replace, relying on the assumption that they will always conform to a limited range of patterns. You will often be warned not to parse XML or HTML *in general* using regexps, and rightly so, because regexps aren't a general solution. But for limited uses they can be sufficient.

If I've guessed your requirements correctly, you could use something like

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(Description, '&lt;[Bb][Rr] ?/?>',
                                           '&#10;&#10;&#10;')"/>
```

That will give you the sample output you showed, as opposed to adding a couple of more BR tags after first occurrence of BR. It will tolerate some variation, e.g. `<br>` or `<BR />`.

This is assuming you can use XSLT 2.0, because `replace()` isn't available in 1.0. If you're limited to 1.0, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this but it says replace function is unknown, so it's XSLT version 1.0

Comment: @2177: Some of the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280079/xsl-multiple-search-and-replace-function show how to do string replacement in XSLT 1.0.