# Missing something re: matching

Tags: xml, xslt, replace, translate

I'm new to XSLT and have run into something I think should work but does not. I'm baffled and hope you can help.

I have the following code:

```
<xsl:template match="text()" name="multiReplace">
    <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

    <xsl:variable name="patterns">
        <pattern>
            <old>A</old>
            <new>B</new>
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
            <old>v</old>
            <new>w</new>
        </pattern>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) >0">
        <xsl:variable name="matchingPatterns" select="$patterns[starts-with($pText, old/node())]"/>

    <!-- Do something with the tree fragment "matchingPatterns" -->

    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

As I understand it, the `select="$patterns[starts-with($pText, old/node())]"` should match only those elements of the `patterns` tree whose node `old` matches the start of the string `$pText`. Instead, `$matchingPatterns` contains all the nodes in the `patterns` tree. I know for a fact that `$pText` does not contain any capital 'A' characters but does contain lowercase 'v's.

Is there something obviously wrong that I'm missing?

Thanks for your help!

-j

p.s., the gist of this code comes from this question: [XSL Multiple search and replace function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280079/xsl-multiple-search-and-replace-function). That code was written for XSLT 1; we're using 2 and it somehow didn't work correctly for me out of the box.

Comment: If you're using XSLT 2.0, then why are you bothering with a recursive named template, instead of using the replace() function?

Comment: Maybe related: if I substitute a literal 'A' in place of `old/node()`, `$matchingPatterns` is empty; if I substitute a literal 'v' `$matchingPatterns` contains all the elements in `patterns`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I can't use `replace()` because I need to replace multiple patterns. These patterns aren't always single characters, so `translate()` isn't useful, either.

Comment: "*I can't use replace() because I need to replace multiple patterns.*" That's no reason: just nest several replace() functions together.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - Thanks, but I think I'm also trying to learn a bit about how XSLT works. I definitely could nest `replace()` statements but I'd like to know why my example doesn't work.

Comment: "*I'd like to know why my example doesn't work.*" Then post a **reproducible** example: XML, XSLT and expected output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k If you need to replace 3 strings, you can chain together 3 calls of replace(). But if you need to replace N strings, where N is not known statically, you need recursion (or a fold()).

Comment: @MichaelKay I see two find/replace pairs hard-coded in the given stylesheet. In any case,  iterating over N pairs should not require the awkward expression OP seems to be struggling with (in fact, I am not sure why it's required even with a XSLT 1.0 type of solution).

Comment: @michael.hor257k There are a finite number of patterns in this example because I wanted a concrete example (as you requested, no less.) If your suggestion using nested `replace()` statements can work with N replacements, then please provide an example of it as an answer -- in other words, if you have an **answer** please post an **answer**. Frankly, it sounds like you continue to comment here simply to have the last word.

Comment: @joemadeus I already suggested you post a **question** in the required format: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- Frankly, I don't care what it sounds like to you. I suggest you refrain from personal remarks.

Comment: @joernadeus If an answerer has misinterpreted your question then you must assume that you have failed to make yourself clear, and the fault is yours not theirs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
<xsl:variable name="patterns">
    <pattern>
        <old>A</old>
        <new>B</new>
    </pattern>
    <pattern>
        <old>v</old>
        <new>w</new>
    </pattern>
</xsl:variable>
```

in XSLT 2.0 the variable is a tree fragment consisting of a root node containing two `pattern` elements so your variable definition should be

```
<xsl:variable name="matchingPatterns" select="$patterns/pattern[starts-with($pText, old)]"/>
```

to select those `pattern` elements that meet the condition.

As an alternative, use `<xsl:variable name="matchingPatterns" select="$patterns[starts-with($pText, old)]"/>` but then make sure you set up

```
<xsl:variable name="patterns" as="element(pattern)*">
    <pattern>
        <old>A</old>
        <new>B</new>
    </pattern>
    <pattern>
        <old>v</old>
        <new>w</new>
    </pattern>
</xsl:variable>
```

In that case your `patterns` variable is a sequence of parentless `pattern` elements, not a tree fragment with a root node containing `pattern` elements.

Comment: Trying this, my editor (Oxygen) tells me, `Required item type of value of variable $patterns is element(Q{}pattern); supplied value has item type element(pattern, xs:untyped)`. Like a lot of errors coming out of XSLT processors this makes no sense to me; specifically, I'm not sure what 'Q{}pattern' refers to. Any insight?

Comment: I am not sure where that problem comes from. Does Oxygen show any error code? Which version of Saxon do you use in Oxygen? Can you show us any context, like a default namespace declaration that might be in scope?

Comment: Yes, to most of those things. It's Saxon-HE 9.6.0.5, the error code is F-XTTE0570. It's failing in compilation, so there's no context but there is `xmlns="http://www.cdisc.org/ns/odm/v1.3"` on the `<xsl:stylesheet>` tag (I assume this is the default.)

Comment: Try setting up the variable with `<xsl:variable name="patterns" as="element(pattern)*" xmlns="">...</xsl:variable>` so that its `pattern` elements created inside are in no namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can work with the old/node(), this may not always work as it will match any node and not just text nodes.

I believe the problem is that you don't iterate over the values in the pattern.
You should add a for-each.

```
<xsl:for-each select="old">
    ...
</xsl:for-each>
```